# Run xUnit-Tests from API-Method

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I have a solution including a `xUnit-Test-Project` and a `API-Web-Application-Project`.

In my `xUnit-Project` I have a couple of Integration/System-Tests.
Now I want to trigger all tests instead of command line `dotnet test` via HTTP-Request `http://myservice.com/run-tests`.

Is there any concept how to archive this?

Comment: You can always use `Process.Start`, but what is the actual problem you want to solve? Why run tests in response to an HTTP request? Are you trying to create your own CI service instead of using an existing one?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to solve two probelms: First, use the integration tests in GitLab CI and secondly, provide the system tests (that tests my complete microservice-apis) via http-API that I can run the tests on demand without needing any command line